# JavaScript - Hard copying primitive

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to copy a variable to a new one, NOT by reference, but by hard copy. In my understanding, JavaScript does a hard copy of primitive types by default. However, I get a reference copy if I do it like this:

```
var u = [0, 12, 34, 56];
var v = u[1];
u[1] = 85;
console.log(v); // returns 85, I want it to return 12
```

So I guess u[1] isn't a primitive type, after all (even though it's just a 12, which is a number, which should be primitive in my understanding). Is there a way I can make a hard copy? I've tried severeal methods I've found here. `v = u[1].slice()` seems to be the obvious choice, it doesn't work however, and there has to be an easier method for this than the 20 line custom functions some advise.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Apparently it works this way, so here's more of the code(without some unimportant parts):

```
var G = [[1, 2, 34, 56],[2, 345, 67, 8],[3, 4],[4, 65, 87]...]; // G contains 99 entries originally
var v;
var u;
var m = 99;
var alt;
var n = edges.length;
G[0].l = 0;
u = G[0].slice(); // now u = [1, 2, 34, 56]
u.l = G[0].l; 
//... ...(some code not doing anything with v and u) 
for (i = 1; i < ( u.length - 1 ) ; i++) {
    alt = u.l + 1;
    console.log(u[i]);
    v = u[i]; 
    u[i] = 9999999; //this is for testing if v is the ith of u or not
    for( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if(G[j][0] == v) { 
        if (  alt < G[j].l ){
          Res[j].l = alt;
          Res[j].previous = u;
        }
      }
    }
    for( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if(G[j][0] == v) { 
        if (  alt < G[j].l ){
          G[j].l = alt;
          G[j].previous = u;
        }
      }
    }
  }    
  return v; //returns 9999999 instead of anythign from the original u, or G for that matter
```

Comment: Erm, `console.log(v)` won't print 85... https://jsfiddle.net/phL3vc68/

Comment: Please show your actual code. The example code you've made doesn't duplicate the actual problem you have; the value of `v` is 12.

Comment: That won't replicate the problem either. https://jsfiddle.net/wdLc5a8o/ Please show an example that you have **confirmed** that it replicates the problem. For example, edit the jsfiddle so that it does what the actual code does.

Comment: @Juhana: https://jsfiddle.net/7vjf82oa/1/ Full code here. Error replicated.

Comment: All I get is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var", and the jsfiddle doesn't even have anything that would print the value. Did you even try it yourself?

Comment: @Juhana I'm sorry, I don't know how to use jsfiddel really. In the Chrome JS console, I can see that the error is replicated with this: https://jsfiddle.net/wdLc5a8o/4/ Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well these two lines are inside of a loop:
from your fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/7vjf82oa/1

```
//reduced to the core problem
while(/*whatever*/){
    for(var i=1; i<u.length-1; ++i){
        v = u[i]; 
        u[i] = 9999999; //this is for testing if v is the ith of u or not
    }
}
return v;
```

you overwrite the values in the first itertion and access them in any further one.

What are you trying to achieve with your code? It seems messed up in so many ways. Maybe we can help to solve the underlying problem.

Like this part:

```
for ( k = 0; k < m ; k++ ) { 
    if ( G[k].l < min ) {
        mini = G[k][0];
        u = G[mini].slice();
        u.l = G[mini].l;
    }
}
G.splice(mini, 1); 
m--;
mini = 0;
```

`mini` seems to reference the index-position of something `min`. 
The way you build G, `G[k][0]` would reference the index-Position inside of G, and `mini = G[k][0]` could be replaced as `mini = k`, except that since you remove Elements from G the indices are completely messed up, so that referencing `u = G[mini].slice()` would result in some sort of fancy shuffle.

Except for the fact that the surrounding condition can never be true. why?
`G[/*any*/].l` is initialized as Infinite.
`u.l` is initialized as 0 and counting up.

```
G[0].l = 0;
u = G[0].slice();
u.l = G[0].l;
//...
alt = u.l + 1;
//...
G[j].l = alt;
```

`min` is initialized as 0 and is never changed.

neither 0..99 nor Infinite can ever be lower than 0

so that `G.splice(mini, 1);` is just a substitute for `G.shift();`

**so again, what are you trying to build? maybe we can help**

Comment: Oh yeah, I noticed that the lesser-sign was on backwards, I fixed it but I copied the older version it seems... I have the array G, take an element u out and process it, and delete it from G since I don't want to process it again. Of course the thing is not finished, that's why there's so much humbug still, my current issue is, that I can't hard copy u[i] into v, as you can see in the fiddle. I want v to stay whatever it is, even when I change u[i].

Comment: @lte__ Once again, the problem is **not** that `v` would change whenever you change `u[i]`. That just doesn't happen. The problem is that the line `v = u[i]` is run at the wrong time.

Comment: I agree with @Juhanna, your code is a mess, **your assumption**, about what is going on and what you problem is, **is wrong** and from your explanations I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. I think G might be a directed unweighted graph and you are trying to build some kind of spanning tree!? and return what exactly?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to clone an object or deep copy , 
there is a few ways to do it.

```
function clone(a) { 
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)); 
}
```